# C# ASP.NET "Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected" on the most basic code

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to test if ASP.NET is working on my customers IIS 7.5 server, the code below works fine on my server.

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<center>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p><%Response.Write(now())%></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the exact same text.aspx file containing the above code he gets the error:

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to 
service this request. Please review the following specific error details and 
modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Source Error:

    Line 3:  <center>
    Line 4:  <h2>Hello</h2>
    Line 5:  <p><%Response.Write(now())%></p>
    Line 6:  </center>
    Line 7:  </body>

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\test.aspx    Line: 5
```

Any ideas why this would be? His server will be running a Swiss version of Windows (if that makes any difference).

Many many thanks.
Steven

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is with the following line:

```
<p><%Response.Write(now())%></p>
```

The statement needs a semicolon since you're strictly writing a C# statement (rather than using any of the binding expressions):

```
<p><% Response.Write(now()); %></p>
```

**Whoops...missed part of the question.**

If this is working on your local server but not the client's remote server, you should make sure that the client's remote server is set to use Visual Basic instead of C# as the language.

You can also add the Language directive directly to the *.aspx page to force the page to use the correct language:

```
<%@ Page Title="Your page's title" Language="VB" %>
```

Comment: @Steven - See my edit. I missed that part of the question. Got distracted by the code. :-P

Answer (score 3):

Check the default language setting in IIS Manager. I think you will find your local machine is set to Visual Basic and the remote server will be set to C#.

**IIS 7 and later**

1. Select the web site in question
2. Select .NET Compilation
3. Compare the setting value for 'Default Language'

Basically your statement is Visual Basic.

```
<%= Response.Write("Blah") %>
```

This is the same statement in C#

```
<%= Response.Write("Blah"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my setup this needs to be:

Response.Write(now());

Please note the ; on the end of the Response.Write.  What version of Windows Server / ASP.NET is install?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a legacy asp.net webforms application and I got this error, multiple of them(207) and all of them on a single .aspx file. That looked quite strange. The ; has nothing to do with the file anywhere. By mistake, the file's "Build Action" changed from "Content" to "Compile". After changing the build action to Content, all the errors vanished.